# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException after updating to Android Studio 4.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-4.2

Google just release Android Studio 4.2 stable. I updated my AS from 4.1 to 4.2.
Now I am getting this error. It's showing error in data binding.

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toCollection(_Collections.kt:1200)
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toMutableList(_Collections.kt:1233)
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toList(_Collections.kt:1224)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.doLoadProcessors(ProcessorLoader.kt:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors(ProcessorLoader.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:42)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Android Studio **4.2.0** and more now comes with Java **11.0.8** shipped and will use it by default which cases this error in deprecated libraries.

The solution is simple, you need to change it to **java (JDK) 1.8** in the menu `File > Project Structure > JDK Location`

[image]

Notices that Android Studio lower than 4.2.0 comes with java 1.8 already

Comment: I am not able to set JDK8 in menu: "Please choose a valid JDK 11 directory"

Comment: EDIT: after providing correct JDK location, it finally accepted. Just another misleading pop-up in Android Studio.

Comment: @adek111 I also get this notice "Please choose a valid JDK 11 directory"

Answer (score 21):

By doing the following steps I solved this problem without replacing  JDK with JAVA 8.

Step 1 : Update the `distributionUrl` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip` in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Step 2: Update your gradle tool classpath to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'` in your root `buid.gradle`

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue, and I alrady solved. I found that Android studio 4.2 will make the JDK update to Java11, it will cause error what you described.

You can delete the Java11 JDK and replace by Java8 (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home).

Also you can uninstall the Android Studio, and reinstall it.

Comment: I cannot find similar path in ubuntu. Can you help?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Ubuntu then just change the JDK location to JAVA (JDK) 1.8 in the menu File > Project Structure > JDK Location

[JDK location android studio 4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NThAi.png)

Answer (score 5):

I thought it was the jdk route, after hours searching, this worked for me

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

in your build.gradle file add and update kotlin_version

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'

 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
```

if you use enableAapt2 remove it from your gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx1536M"
#android.enableAapt2=false
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are coming here having **Android Studio Arctic Fox** which comes by default with Java 11, you need to use java 1.8 to find necessary classes which are completely removed in java 11 upgrade.

Path to set in Android Studio Arctic Fox is as follows

**Preferences > Build execution Deployment > Gradle > Gradle Sdk**

Choose Download JDK then Java 1.8.x version and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

there are two method to solve this problem

1. roll back to Java 8
2. update gradle tools 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' like 4.2.1(I used)
   maybe you will encounter "Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided" problem, add below to you App build.gradle

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```